# umount: /: target is busy

Tags: lvm, ubuntu-gnome, umount

When I ran the command

`umount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root` I I got :

```
umount: /: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
```

I tried some different options with the command `lsof` and `fuser`, but it didn't work so far.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What issue, exactly? are you really trying to unmount the root filesystem of your running OS?

Comment: This is a LVM partiton. I'm not an expert, but I should be able to resize this partition, but it is not the case actually.

Answer (score 29):

Please try this commands:

```
umount -l /PATH/OF/BUSY-DEVICE
umount -f /PATH/OF/BUSY-NFS(NETWORK-FILE-SYSTEM)
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878707/umount-a-busy-device

Comment: How could I find the path of busy-nfs?

Comment: That command (-f) stands for --force, check the link, the author put it that way but you can use the path of your busy device. Also: http://oletange.blogspot.com/2012/04/umount-device-is-busy-why.html

Comment: my autofs nfs share still hangs when I use `-f`

Comment: umount -l worked for me. Thx.

Comment: It's unbelievable how well this generally works when nothing else will. Though I run the -f and -l flags both on the same /dev/mapper/ path to the object (-f generally telling me whatever it is is not mounted though). So perhaps all that is really needed is the -l. NFS does not factor into my recovery scenarios, so I have no reason to look for an NFS path. 

This technique has saved me on a few occasions though. It will absolutely let you rip the filesystem out from under you though, so proceed with caution.

Comment: `umount -l`does not actually unmount the filesystem. Please be sure to understand the implications of using `umount -l`.

Answer (score 0):

try these:

`dmsestup ls`

if your output contain "ubuntu--gnome--vg-root" then try to deactivate lvm volume at first, then try to umount your volume:

```
lvchange -an "Path-to-Your-LVM-Volume (in this case: /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root)"

umount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root
```